# Where is visual studio 2017 remote gdb debugger?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, visual-studio-2017

I build a Linux C program in Visual studio 2017 by **"console application(Linux)"**. When I set a break point in the program to debug my program remotely, I run **"F5"** begin to debug, however, the program didn't stop at the break point and run to the end. I find my program doesn't provide a **"gdb remote debugger"**, how to configure it?

Comment: "Linux C program in Visual studio 2017", but why ? Sorry. I think you need to provide gdb executable path to visual studio and obviously install it before.

Comment: "C program in Visual studio 2017" but why? You should use a modern, standard compliant C compiler instead.

Comment: In my ubuntu server, I install gdbserver openssh etc, and I configure remote server access, I can compile and run C program correctly on remote ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

This option is available for Makefile project, so you need create project type as "Makefile project (Linux)".